# I'm working on reading and writing to files with c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi guys I'm working on my last assignment of the computer science class. I think I'm doing everything fine but something is wrong. Can you take a look at it and tell what I'm doing wronger here.

here is what I get when I try to submit online on zybooks site:
"Your program produced no output"
Expected:
Ryan Hermle
22.99
Lochness Monster
3.50
Wonder Woman
123456.78

here are instructions from professor:

Constructor:

Takes a string parameter and stores that as fileName. Does not need to do anything else.

append:

Takes a record as a parameter that contains a string and a double
Open an output file stream in append mode using fileName
set its precision to 2 and fixed
Output the name, newline, the money, newline

searchName:

Open an input file stream with fileName
Loop while a getline and a double extraction are successful
if the string parameter is equal to the name read from the getline, then return the double
If the loop finishes without finding anything, return -1 to indicate that name was not found.

getData:

Open an input file stream with fileName
Construct an ostringstream
Set its precision to 2 and fixed
Loop while a getline and a double extraction are successful
ignore the \n left by the >> extraction
write the string, newline, double, newline to the ostringstream
return the string contained by the ostringstream

here is my main:

```
#include "Database.h"

int main()
{
    Database db("data.txt");
    db.append(Record{"Ryan Hermle", 22.99});
    db.append(Record{"Lochness Monster", 3.50});
    db.append(Record{"Wonder Woman", 123456.78});
}

and here is my Database.cpp file:


#include "Database.h"

Database::Database(string file)
{
    fileName = file;
}

void Database::append(Record data)
{
    ofstream out;
    out.open(fileName, ios::app);
    out << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    cout << data.name << endl;
    cout << data.money << endl;
    out.close();
}

double Database::searchName(string n)
{
    Record s;
    ifstream in;
    in.open(fileName);
    while (getline(in, n) >> s.money)
    {
        in.ignore();
        if (n == s.name)
        {
            return s.money;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

string Database::getData()
{
    Record s;
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(fileName);
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    while(getline(ifs, s.name) >> s.money)
    {
        ifs.ignore();
        oss << s.name << endl << s.money << endl;
        cout << oss.str();
    }
     return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: _I think I'm doing everything fine but something is wrong._ At first short glance, everything is looking fine. Please, describe your specific issue in detail. (This site is not dedicated to review.) What did you observe in debugger?

Comment: Here is a little feedback.
Your program produced no output.
 Expected output
Ryan Hermle
22.99
Lochness Monster
3.50
Wonder Woman
123456.78

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add details. Again: Did you debug your program?

Comment: You're not writing anything to `out` in `append`, you're writing to `cout`.

Comment: I did not get that.

Comment: Why is ```cout``` used when file streams are been opened?

Comment: it took me a while to get that because i'm new to c++ writing to files. Thanks for your help. That was only the error in my Program.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone who replied to my post. I was able figure out the error in my program.

The error was in append Function:
 cout << data.name << endl;
 cout << data.money << endl;

It should be like this:
 out << data.name << endl;
 out << data.money << endl;